# EPERM: operation not permitted, write

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Can Anyone Help me to fix this Error ??
This error comes without editing or adding anything in my code which is in react js, node js. And I don't know how I can fix it

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you running your local server ? Maybe inside wsl ?

Comment: @AntonioPantano  I honestly don't understand what you mean exactly but I use
XAMMP, LocalHost, running on Chrome. And working in Windows System ..
Hope you got the answer

Comment: I meant WLS (Windows Linux Subsystem).  I experienced issues with file permissions but if you're not using it that's not the case.